# Using fileX if GUI button1 Pressed or fileY if GUI button2 pressed in Processing

Tags: android, user-interface, processing

I have question.

I have written a small program that plays a different sound (in english) everytime the user presses on a specific part of the screen. Different sound for different part of screen. EASY ENOUGH.

Now I want to improve it by creating some buttons (the basics of which I should manage) that would allow the user to select/change a language, so that when he press on the same spot he would either get English or Spanish depending on which button he selected.

I want to know.
How do I do this in Processing?
DO I create a class for each button or do I somehow intergrate the code into the scetch?

I would really appriciate some guidance.
I hope my explenation was clear enough.

Thank you

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either write it by yourself or import one of the many GUI libraries available for Processing:

- [G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/),
- [Guido](https://github.com/fjenett/Guido),
- [Interfascia](http://www.superstable.net/interfascia/) (still in alpha phase),
- [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) (recommended)...

For the full list of libraries see the [Processing Reference](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/).

If you want to write it by yourself, you could create a **button class** and a **drop-down class** that stores ([has-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)) instances of the button class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The GUI part I get and should not be to difficult. Just some clarity on the has-a relationship. I would basically create a class for each language with the different images and sound in this class. Then I would call this class when the specific button is pressed. Right?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I just created my own buttons cheers.